# Implementing the GCM in android app just for pop notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have android app which is basically mobile server communication app ,when I send data through this app it gets updated on on all the devices which have this application, Like I send Person "name", "phone no"  and some description from this application then It will store onto my online database and will be shown on the this app in the form of listview,NoW I want whenever I put or send data through this app,A push notification or popup notification will be appear on the devices which have  this application, I am trying to implement GCM Google cloud messaging AND follow this Tutorial:

But I didnot Know how  can I Integrate this with my app, would you please help me and suggest me some blog or tutorial regarding my current senerio.

Answer (score 0):

You are using old concept which has been deprecated.Now it is recommended to implement google cloud messaging(GCM) using google play services library. See this tutorial. Hope this helps

http://techlovejump.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/